# Draw dotted line for selection in text using swing

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

Can anyone know about how to show dotted line when select text so user can drag that text?

[image: Selected text when user selected text.]

Answer (score 4):

You can add highlights like it's described here http://java-sl.com/tip_vertical_selection.html and define own `HighLightPainter`. In the painter define `BasicStroke` for dotted line and use drawRect with the stroked line.